# Order by not working on PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQl and I have created one function which is mentioned below. What I want that when I am running SELECT query in query tool then it working fine and giving result what I want but when I am executing below function then order by not working. Stageno is a "character varying". How can I fix that ?

```
-- FUNCTION: public.getauditquestion(integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.getauditquestion(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getauditquestion(
    auditid integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(audit_ques_id bigint, audit_id integer, activityname character varying, question_id integer, question character varying, answer_type integer, answer_lov integer, answertypename character varying, ok_notok integer, oknotokname character varying, answer_min character varying, answer_max character varying, uom integer, uomname character varying, correct_ans integer, created_by integer, created_date timestamp without time zone, stage character varying, stageno character varying, description character varying, severity character varying, who character varying, how character varying, "when" character varying, "where" character varying)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000.0
AS $function$

    BEGIN
     Return Query 
        select am.audit_ques_id, am.audit_id  ,ddl3.dd_value AS activityName  , am.question_id , 
        ddl2.question AS question, am.answer_type, am.answer_lov, ddl4.dd_value AS answerTypeName, am.ok_notok , 
        ddl5.dd_value AS okNotOkName, am.answer_min, am.answer_max, am.uom, ddl13.dd_value AS uomname, am.correct_ans, 
        am.created_by, am.created_date,ddl6.dd_value AS stage, ddl14.dd_value AS stage_no, ddl7.description, ddl8.dd_value AS severity, 
        ddl9.dd_value AS who , ddl10.dd_value AS how , ddl11.dd_value AS "when"  , ddl12.dd_value AS "where"
        from audit_ques_detail am left join audit_master ddl1 on ddl1.audit_id=am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl3 on ddl3.dd_id=ddl1.activity_id
        left join question_master ddl2 on ddl2.question_id=am.question_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id = am.answer_type
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = am.ok_notok
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl2.stage
        left join question_master ddl7 on ddl7.question_id = am.question_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id = ddl2.severity
        left join dd_type_details ddl9 on ddl9.dd_id = ddl2.who
        left join dd_type_details ddl10 on ddl10.dd_id = ddl2.how
        left join dd_type_details ddl11 on ddl11.dd_id = ddl2.when
        left join dd_type_details ddl12 on ddl12.dd_id = ddl2.where
        left join dd_type_details ddl13 on ddl13.dd_id = am.uom
        left join dd_type_details ddl14 on ddl14.dd_id = am.stage_no
        where am.audit_id = auditid and am.isActive = 1 ORDER BY cast(ddl14.dd_value AS Integer);
    END;


$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.getauditquestion(integer)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? What is the error you get?

Comment: not getting data in correct order when executing above function

Comment: How exactly are you using the function? And what is the order you get? And what is the order you want?

Comment: I want order in ascending form but I am getting order in which rows inserted in database.

Comment: If I am running only query in query tool then it is giving correct order.